# Eliminación de una fila en un DataRow[] C#

Tags: c#, .net, aspx, datarow

Hago un llamado a BD y el me trae una info la cual ordeno de la siguiente manera:

```
Backlog.GetDocAllUsersDataTable data = servicio.GetDocAllUsersDataTable(string.Empty)

DataRow[] rows = data.Select().OrderBy(x => x["NombreUsuario"]).ToArray;
```

En mi array 'rows' me quedan ordenados los ítem de BD pero después hago una condición para eliminar unos ítems, lo intenté con

```
rows[0].Delete();
data.AcceptChanges();
```

Pero lo que hace es formatear todos los campos de la posición 0 más no la elimina, es decir que si llegan 26 registros me siguen quedando los mismos 26 y necesito que me queden 25.
Gracias ...

Answer (score 0):

Usar [RemoveAt](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77ed73c3-fb56-414a-bacf-0cdcd41afff4/remove-element-from-an-array-of-string?forum=csharpgeneral); tal que en vez de:

```
rows[0].Delete();
```

usa:

```
rows.RemoveAt(0);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda pero me dice: DataRow no contiene una definición para "RemoveAt" ni un método de extensión accesible ...

Comment: @NicoFlorez debes tener `System.Collections` incluida en el `using`; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.removeat?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: gracias nuevamente pero ya está incluido el [System.Collections]  y aún sigue el mismo error...

Answer (score 0):

**RemoveAt** es un método de DataTable en el que envías el DataRow que deseas eliminar. Se puede usar:

```
data.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
```

o bien

```
data.Rows.Remove(rows[0]);
```

Espero sea útil a alguien